# Constraints dont work on custom cell

Tags: xcode, constraints

I have a Table View with Constraints equal width and height. Inside have custom cell with some values.

[image]

I think cell values should be configured right? So when I test just see half cell.

I have to add some constraints more?

Thanks

PS: I try to add missing constraints, but it was worse
PS2: I reset to suggested constraints and nothing.

Comment: Add ps2, suggested constraints dont work too